# Conditional Independence and Marginalization

Tags: machine-learning, probability, conditional-probability, independence, graphical-model

I'm currently reading Bishops: Pattern Matching and Machine Learning and ran into an equation I didn't grasp. Page 373, Graphical Models, section 8.2.1.

He says:

...

Given the joint distribution:

\begin{equation}
p(a,b,c) = p(a|c)p(b|c)p(c)
\end{equation}
We can investigate whether *a* and *b* are independent by marginalizing both sides with respect to *c*, 
 \begin{equation}
p(a,b) = \sum_c p(a|c)p(b|c)p(c)
\end{equation}
and in general this does NOT factorize to the product:
 \begin{equation}
p(a)p(b)
\end{equation}

...

My question is why it would not factor into the product above? Seems reasonable that once *c* has been marginalized out that's **exactly** the product you would get?

Summing over all values of *c* should result in:
 \begin{equation}
\sum_c p(c) = 1 
\end{equation}
and thus we should arrive at the product, 
 \begin{equation}
p(a,b) = \sum_c p(a|c)p(b|c)=p(a)p(b)
\end{equation}
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Note that, in general, 
$$\sum_c p(a|c) p(b|c) p(c) \ne p(a) p(b) \sum_c p(c)\,. $$

The fact that $\sum_c p(c) = 1$ can only be used if $p(a|c) = p(a)$ and $p(b|c) = p(b)$, which is not always true. In general $\sum_c p(c) = 1$ will not be useful. Consider for example, consider for $c \in \{1,2\}$

$$p(a|c)  = ce^{-ca}, p(b|c) = ce^{-cb},  \text{ and } p(c) = 1/2$$

Then
\begin{align*}
p(a,b) & = \sum_c p(a|c) p(b|c) p(c)\\
& = \sum_c \dfrac{ce^{-ca} ce^{-cb}}{2} \\
& = \sum_c \dfrac{c^2 e^{-c(a+b)}}{2}\\
& = \dfrac{e^{-(a+b)}}{2} + \dfrac{4e^{-2(a+b)}}{2}\\
& = \dfrac{e^{-(a+b)}}{2}\left(1 + 4e^{-(a+b)} \right)
\end{align*}

The above cannot be factored in $p(a)p(b)$.